# Testing HTTP DELETE requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm currently learning ruby on rails and rspec and have come across a problem. I'm trying to test that when I hit the delete button for a shopping cart I created then that cart is deleted. My test is:

```
context "Delete Cart" do
    Given!(:product){FactoryGirl.create(:product)}
    Given!(:cart){FactoryGirl.create(:cart)}
    Given{add_product(product, cart)}
    Given {get "/"}
    Given {xhr :post, "/line_items?product_id=#{product.id}"}
    When {xhr :delete, "/carts/#{cart.id}"}
    Then {Cart.exists?(cart.id)}
  end
```

This passes, which it shouldn't since the cart should have been deleted. Any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never written tests like this before with rspec. Generally I wrap my actual tests in `it "..." do` method calls.

Comment: It's using a gem called rspec-given

Comment: yeah, I figured there might be something going on there. Just checking for low-hanging fruit. I don't have a good answer for this question, though. Sorry.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code the test is calling, specifically the relevant controller actions.

Comment: you can probably find out on your own once you debug it properly by either looking into the logs or setting breakpoints appropriately. have a look at this blog post for more suggestions http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/